# Creating map book series with blank pages between maps using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I am looking to create a series of maps each one highlighting the camping pitch,. I would like to put the number of the pitch highlighted on either page before or after to allow duplex printing of map on one side and pitch number on the other side?.

Is this possible using ArcGIS Pro with or without python?

See image of camping pitches - [image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would use ArcPy and starting code that is included in the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x help on [Creating a map book with facing pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-a-map-book-with-facing-pages.htm).

That code will take some adapting from `arcpy.mapping` to `arcpy.mp` but the key thing is that you will export two sets of pages from two separate layouts, which could be kept in the same project.